# Are Event Handlers processed Asynchronously?

Tags: vb.net, events, asynchronous, event-handling

In VB .NET, when you call RaiseEvent X(), is the function that handles the event X processed asynchronously or synchronously. I was under the impression that RaiseEvent and the processing of the event were Synchronous unless created explictly on another thread. I've been told otherwise though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Events are raised synchronously by default. Since [`MulticastDelegates`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.multicastdelegate.aspx) are designed to support asynchronous invocation it is possible to invoke the delegates in an event's invocation list asynchronously but this is not the default behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I just did some testing also...

```
Public Sub MyHandler() Handles Complete
    MsgBox("My Handler - Beginning 5 second sleep")
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
    MsgBox("My Handler - Awoken")
End Sub


Public Sub SomeFunction()
    MsgBox("Some function - Raising Event")
    RaiseEvent Complete()
    MsgBox("Some function - After Event")
End Sub
```

Output:
     Some function - Raising Event
     My Handler - Beginning 5 second sleep
     My Handler - Awoken
     Some function - After Event